# `aws sts get-caller-identity` returns account info for previous account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sts

i previously was using aws cli for an old account. since then, i've reconfigured the cli using `aws configure` and provided the access_key_id/secret_access_key associated w/ an entirely new account. however, when i run `aws sts get-caller-identity`, it returns the account/userId/arn associated w/ my old account. any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You probably have the other accounts access / secret still exported in the shell you are currently in. Try a new shell and see what happens there. Then e.g. run `env` on linux to see all env variables and then maybe go with https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/813/175925 .

Comment: thanks! that was the tip i needed. i had some envvars overriding my config